# safe usage of Timers in multi-threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have to launch a timer and display it on screen while i am doing other stuff, so i decided to implement my timer in another thread here is my code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            Thread th1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadCall1));
            th1.IsBackground = true;
            th1.Start();

            secret = a.Next(0, 101);
            counter = 0;
            label2.Text = "";
            button1.Enabled = false;

        }

public void updatetimer()
        {
            Stopwatch aa = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            TimeSpan ts;
            while (true)
            {
                ts = aa.Elapsed;
                string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}:{3:000}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds);
                label3.Text = elapsedTime;
            }
        }
        public delegate void threadJob();

        public void threadCall1()
        {
            Invoke(new threadJob(updatetimer));
        }
```

whenever i run and click that button, my application freezes from responding to any other action ? is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: use background worker

Comment: [This article](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/246911-c%23-multi-threading-in-a-gui-environment/) explains the details of multi-threading in GUIs. Note also that it uses the system thread pool, which is the recommended way of moving small work items into the background in .NET.

Comment: @jhyap any further hints! sample code!

Comment: google search background worker c# sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something more like this:

```
    private bool Timing = false;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timing = true;
        Thread th1 = new Thread(updatetimer);
        th1.IsBackground = true;
        th1.Start();

        secret = a.Next(0, 101);
        counter = 0;
        label2.Text = "";
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timing = false;
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void updatetimer()
    {
        Stopwatch aa = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        TimeSpan ts;
        while (Timing)
        {
            ts = aa.Elapsed;
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}:{3:000}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds);
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                label3.Text = elapsedTime;
            });
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }
```

Comment: by the way, it shows the same behavior even if removing `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);` !

Comment: Visually it will be the same.  Look at the **Task Manager**, however, and you'll see that without the call to Sleep() your app will use a ridiculous amount of CPU cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation. `Control.Invoke`:

> Executes the specified delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle.

You're calling the Form's `Invoke` method from within your new thread.. which is essentially pointless.

You should move your control access to its own function and call *only that function* using `Invoke`. Leave the calculations up to the thread.

Comment: i didn't understand much since there is no example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa334883(v=vs.71).aspx), could you please give an example whether using my above code or any other sample